# Prevent two sets of labels from overlapping in a bar chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a bar chart in a dashboard that needs to be dynamically updateable. I've inserted two graphs in order to have two sets of labels in different places.

Unfortunately, when the value is `0` or `No grade`, they overlap. Manually adjusting them is not effective as they just move when the data refreshes.

Any ideas how to deal with this? I'm trying to keep it clean so I don't want to add a legend.

[image]

Comment: As a work around, have the data that is populating the grade, as the data used for the x-axis perhaps ?

Comment: Could you share the data you have used to make graph so that we try to reproduce the situation, will help me & others to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PeterH's answer does indeed solve the problem:

As a work around, have the data that is populating the grade, as the data used for the x-axis perhaps ?

I just moved the text labels below the X axis.